# Google Maps and Trackin service

Tags: google-maps

I have a personal project to create a tracking service using filemaker, the gps of a tracking device on my car and Google maps.
I am totally new on Google maps.
Any advice on where to start? Of course on google site but I am completely lost how interact with google maps to pass it parameters of latitud and longitud that the device is sending me.
Thankis in advance

Answer (score 0):

Start with the V3 API code samples..

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Answer (score 0):

This is something I have written previously for customers. As I cannot share my customers application, what I can do is point you in the direction of an alternative application to get your teeth into and well on your way to giving you exactly what you want:

http://bit.ly/12Z7Cqg